# Div exceeds the height of the body

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know this may be an usual problem but i haven't found a solution in this website nor others.

I'm trying to implement a pure css tab system but somehow TAB2 exceeds the height of the body.

You can find the source code here: http://goo.gl/4JU2pz

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I need a bit more information, can't really see what you mean from the fiddle

Comment: You have too many floating elements. Dimensions of floating elements aren't taken in consideration when calculating the dimensions of their containers that's why you don't see the height adjustment when switching tabs.

Comment: Unrelated, but why would you shorten a fiddle url? If anything, makes me less likely to even click it.

Comment: @chriz: When you click on TAB 2, it covers the whole footer instead of staying on the inside.

Comment: @88MPG: I tried posting the actual link, but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the "Position: absolute" property for class ".tabs .tab-content". Try to remove this and see. Your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `margin-bottom`?

http://jsfiddle.net/gumw0yuc/1/

Comment: I don't see any change from the original fiddle.

Comment: You can see changes on my link.

Comment: I meant in regards to the original problem there is no change. OP's issue is still present.